# How do I send a user pool user a custom email when invoking forgot_password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

AWS Cognito IDP (Identity Provider) is a service AWS provides for managing users of your service via user pools. Cognito provides a variety of APIs and one can programmatically use Cognito via boto3, the Python wrapper for AWS.

The forgot_password method is used when a user has forgotten their password:

```
   cog.forgot_password(ClientId=USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID, Username=req["username"])
```

This sends an email to a user with a six digit code that the user can use to change their password.

The thing is, I want the email to contain custom content along with the six digit code. I am certain this must be possible, that there must be a way to have templated content and use that templated content to send the user an email with custom content that also contains the six digit code.

Does anyone know, when invoking the forgot_password for AWS Cognito IDP using boto3 how I can send a custom email that contains the six digit code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Cognito invokes custom triggers before sending an email or phone verification message or a multi-factor authentication (MFA) code, allowing you to customize the message dynamically.

You need to create a lambda function and use CustomMessage_ForgotPassword as triggerSource. For example:

```
if(event.userPoolId === "theSpecialUserPool") {
    // Identify why was this function invoked
    if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword") {
        // Ensure that your message contains event.request.codeParameter. This is the placeholder for code that will be sent
        event.response.emailSubject = "Forgot Password";
        event.response.emailMessage = "Your customized text here" + event.request.codeParameter + " and your verification code";
    }
    // Create custom message for other events
}
```

Then integrate this lambda function with your cognito pool by doing the following:

AWS Console -> Cognito -> Pool -> General Settings -> Triggers -> Custom Message.

So every time that a user call forgot password your pool will trigger the above lambda instead of the default forgot password AWS cognito lambda.

Reference

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html